# Generic list in Interface

Tags: c#, list, interface

Am creating an interface and I require it to be able to handle different list types, what should I be using?

Am using classes which I use in Lists of `List<Person>` , `List<Charge>`, `List<Other>`

I did try this interface but its not the right Generic List Type, or type I am using

```
interface iGeneric
{
    void Add(object obj);
    void Delete(object obj);
    void Update(object obj);
    object View(object obj);
}
```

And the charge class inheriting the iGeneric interface

```
public class Charge : iGeneric
{
    public Charge()
    {
        Description = "na";
    }

public void Add(object obj)
    {
        //Add  a new charge to the database
        List<Charge> myCharge = new List<Charge>();
        string cn = ConfigurationHelper.getConnectionString("Scratchpad");

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn))
        {
            con.Open();

            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblCharge ([Description],[Amount]) VALUES (@Description, @Amount)", con))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Description", NewCharge.Description));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Amount", NewCharge.Amount));

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("New Charge added successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to insert new charge.");
            }
        }
```

Ideally I would like to set each List and class when I define the List i.e.

```
List<Charge> myCharge = new List<Charge>();
List<Person> myPerson = new List<Person>();
List<Other> myOther = new List<Other>();
```

Comment: "its not liking it" - what does that mean? What error message? What observations? `Charge.Add` expects an `object`, but `iGeneric.Add` expects a `T`. This cannot compile. And what does the bottom code block (where you initialize various lists) to do with your question?

Comment: I changed it to bring it inline with what I was doing... did try List T but I didnt have the correct syntax/ command. The block at bottom is the 3 Lists I want to use via an interface....The interface should be able to take any list I pass

Comment: I still have no idea what "its not liking it" means *specifically*. Also, I'm neither sure about what you are asking nor what you are trying to achieve. Please try to clarify your question. For instance, towards the end, you write: "Ideally I would like to set each List and class when I define the List i.e." But the following code block (the list initialization) looks fine, so what's the problem?

Comment: so I want a common interface that can accept a list of any type, it will have common functions i.e. CRUD. The main requirement is I can pass any List <Class> to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do this with generics. Use something like this:

```
public interface IGenericManager<T>
{
    void Add(T obj);
    void Delete(T obj);
    void Update(T obj);
    T View(T obj);
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonManager : IGenericManager<Person>
{
    public void Add(Person obj)
    {
        // TODO: Implement
    }

    public void Delete(Person obj)
    {
        // TODO: Implement
    }

    public void Update(Person obj)
    {
        // TODO: Implement
    }

    public Person View(Person obj)
    {
        // TODO: Implement
        return null;
    }
}
```